# Read a file line by line and pass to a method

Tags: python

I have a text file that has around 10 sentences.

```
My Name is Kerry.
I am a female.
My pet is a cat.
It's name is Ronald.
I hate rats.
```

What i want to do is to read a sentence from this text file and pass it on to the `fineSearch` method that i have written.

```
def fineSearch(wd):
    for line in wd:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            if word.endswith(('ts.','ld')):
                print word
```

MAIN

```
ws = linebylineread('tx.txt')
fineSearch("It's name is Ronald.") # THIS IS FOR DEMO PURPOSE ONLY.

NOTE: I WANT TO READ JUST ONE LINE AT A TIME FROM THE TX.TXT FILE AND PASS IT TO THE METHOD THAT I HAVE WRITTEN.

NOTE: I HAVE NOTICED THAT THE CODE WORKS WHEN I PASS THE WHOLE CHUNK OF TEXT AND NOT A LINE.
```

When i pass    `fineSearch(ws)` it works but it reads the entire file, when i print the text it shows as; `My Name is Kerry.\n I am a female.\n My pet is a cat\n` etc. I just want to be able to send ONE line to the method i have written.

Comment: What's function `linebylineread`?

Comment: what's with the ALL CAPS dude?

Comment: @MaximeLorant it reads the file line by line

Comment: Unrelated problem - `It's name is Ronald.` should be `Its name is Ronald.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the code to work on a line, you need to change the `fineSearch(...)` function as follows:

```
def fineSearch(wd):
    for word in wd.strip().split():
            if word.endswith(('ts.','ld.')): # test for ld. at end
                print word
```

And then, you can iterate over the file line by line using the following code.

```
>>> with open('testFile.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            fineSearch(line)


rats. # Output. If you wanted Ronald. too, you need to change `ld` in the code to `ld.`
```

Your initial code seems to work on a list of lines, something like `readlines(...)` would provide, but `readlines(...)` reads the whole file into memory whereas you seem to want to iterate over the file line by line.

Comment: I just tried this, `fineSearch ('It's name is Ronald.')`, and it doesn't give any output. Help